# What languages can be debugged under gdb and how

Tags: python, ruby, gdb

I've read [here](https://stripe.com/blog/exploring-python-using-gdb) that gdb can be used to debug languages like Python or Ruby. How is it possible? Which another languages can gdb debug? How to debug those languages under gdb?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

gdb can primarily debug compiled languages.  It has built-in support for several (from memory, C, C++, Ada, Fortran, Pascal, Modula-2, and Go), but you can also use the C language support with any language and at least get something done.

It has a bit of support for JIT-compiled languages, but you have to write some of your own support, and it doesn't provide a way to hook into the expression parser.

It doesn't have any direct support for interpreted languages.  You can write pretty-printers and frame filters to display some information more nicely.  The blog you linked to was about using knowledge of the implementation of a language to help with debugging scripts written in that language -- this is definitely possible, but it's not easy.

It's been a long-standing wish-list item to extend the gdb Python interface to allow better multi-language debugging.  However, as far as I know, nobody is actively working on this.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I would like to ask if there is some special modules needed for `gdb` or `gdb` needs to be compiled with some flags etc for debugging those languages? Also how to start debugging those languages will e.g. `gdb script.py` work?